# Get RenderScript Progress

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I'm using the forEach_root method to compute an image on Android.

```
RenderScript RS=RenderScript.create(context);

Allocation inPixelsAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(RS, inBitmap,
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT); 
Bitmap out=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Allocation outPixelsAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(RS, out,
Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

mScript.forEach_root(inPixelsAllocation,outPixelsAllocation);
outPixelsAllocation.copyTo(out);
return out;
```

This works fine, but however, since there can be a huge amount of data (more than 18 Million Pixels to process), it can take some time.
Is there any possibility to get the current process of the RenderScript forEach-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "current process" that you mean status (so that you can display a progress bar or something like that). There is no way to know how much work has been done, nor how much remains that is developer-visible. In fact, I don't think we could actually truly compute that, since you could make any single cell of your kernel instance take significantly longer with a simple if statement looking for that pixel coordinate. So, I have two potential suggestions for you, depending on what it is that you think the status information will get you: 1) Use a spinner if you are trying to make a progress bar and want to let the user know that you are indeed still working; 2) If you need this for synchronization, anything you do with the input/output allocations later will wait until the kernel completes (i.e. your copyTo operation will block appropriately).

Comment: Okay, I almost thought this. However, since the process can take very long, just showing a Spinner is not very userfriendly. And since RenderScript is designed for processing huge datasets, there should really be any kind of callback, which is fired at least at some times when some of the Kernels are ready. Really looking forward for that!